# How to return a String Array using Jsoup?

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-asynctask, jsoup

How can I store all the href links I extracted using jsoup library to a String Array?

Then display it all inside a TextView?

I do not know how to use **AsyncTask** with **String Array**, nor do I know how to do a **FOR LOOP** during the extractions the href links from Google. I don't know what to put for the condition to make the **FOR LOOP** stop. My current code only returns the last href link. I hope someone can illustrate it to me. I appreciate your time!

```
package com.example.jsouptestarray;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import com.example.jsouptestarray.R;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new MyTask().execute();

         }


    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Document doc;
            String linkText = ""; 

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/").get();
                 Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
                 for (Element el : links) { 
                     linkText = el.attr("href");
                        System.out.println("Href Found!");
                        System.out.println("Href attribute is : "+linkText);
                 }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return linkText;   
          } 


          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {        
            //if you had a ui element, you could display the title
            ((TextView)findViewById (R.id.textView2)).append ( result  );
          }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `AsyncTask` class as to return String ArrayList from `doInBackground` :

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

ArrayList<String> arr_linkText=new ArrayList<String>();

          @Override
          protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Document doc;
            String linkText = ""; 

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/").get();
                 Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
                 for (Element el : links) { 
                     linkText = el.attr("href");
                     arr_linkText.add(linkText); // add value to ArrayList
                 }
              } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
             }
            return arr_linkText;     //<< retrun ArrayList from here
          } 


          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {        

          // get all value from result to display in TextView
               TextView textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
              for (String temp_result : result) {
                System.out.println("links :: "+temp_result);

                           textview.append (temp_result +"\n");
             }
          }
        }
```

Comment: At the "return arr_linkText;" It's telling me to insert finally to complete the TryStatment .. how to fix it? Also on the "onPostExecute" when I do the For Loop, how can I find out how many href links are inside the Array? Can you please update it on your answer? Thank You!

Comment: It prints it out beautifully on the system log, just one little thing. How can you also print out it inside a TextView with a new line? Thank you!

Comment: Never mind I got it to work. You are a lifesaver, I appreciate your help so much!